# Does the program need to exit for Valgrind to work?

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

**Note:**
 1. I tried passing the flag `--vgdb=yes`, but in this case the process doesn't run at all.
 2. I am not in favor of instrumenting my code.

**Problem:**
I am trying to run valgrind on a custom OS (linux based) user-space process that runs forever. How can I get the Valgrind stats for mem-leaks in this case, i.e., the process runs forever.
In its current state, I started the process with Valgrind and see these logs:

```
==6561== Memcheck, a memory error detector                                                                                                                                                                         
==6561== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6561== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6561== Command: xyz_server
==6561== Parent PID: 3056
. . . . 
==6561== 
==6561== Thread 12: 
==6561== Syscall param timer_create(evp) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==6561==    at 0x84949BD: timer_create (in /lib64/librt-2.12.so)
==6561==    by 0x56D518E: api_1 (in . . .) // removed proprietary lib name
==6561==    by 0x74DDDD2: api_2 (in . . .) // removed proprietary lib name
==6561==    by 0x827A9BB: start_thread (pthread_create.c:301)
==6561==  Address 0x1fb37a50 is on thread 12's stack
==6561==
```

There are no stats here. For eg, if I run valgrind with same args on `ls`:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full ls -l
==12584== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12584== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12584== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12584== Command: ls -l
==12584==
. . .
==12584== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12584==     in use at exit: 18,424 bytes in 10 blocks
==12584==   total heap usage: 71 allocs, 61 frees, 63,312 bytes allocated
. . .
==12584== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12584==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12584==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12584==      possibly lost: 18,424 bytes in 10 blocks
==12584==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12584==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12584==
==12584== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12584== ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2
. . .
```

How can I get similar stats for my program? My process never exits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do memory check on a daemon program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276044/how-to-do-memory-check-on-a-daemon-program)

Comment: @cad, doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @ks1322: vgdb doesnt seem to work in my case. And the other answers talk about instrumenting the code, not in favor of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger leak search from the shell or from gdb while your program is running.

For that, the valgrind gdbserver must be active. The gdbserver is activated by default (it is disabled if you give --vgdb=no). There is no reason why giving --vgdb=yes would make your program not run.

On the other hand, giving --vgdb-error=0 means your program will wait for a connection from gdb/vgdb to continue.

To trigger a leak search from the shell, you can for example use:

```
vgdb leak_search full
```